# Есть ли слово "давне́е" как сравнительная степень в смысле "более давно"?

Tags: прилагательные, степени-прилагательных

И как вообще определять наверняка, правомерна ли такая форма у любого прилагательного без слова *более*? Простите, если я спрашиваю то, что все знают или должны знать и что я не знаю, где это посмотреть.

Я почти уверен, что *давнее* нельзя говорить, но хочу понять почему и чем надо руководствоваться в таких случаях для точного уяснения вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я почти уверен, что *давнее* нельзя говорить...

Думаю, что те, кто так говорит, с Вами не согласятся.

Из учебного пособия Т.Г. Фоминой **["Русское ударение"](https://books.google.ru/books?id=eeYYAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%22%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&dq=%22%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5%22%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYv_ipyNztAhVwk4sKHaykDb4Q6AEwCHoECAgQAg)**:

> …формы сравнительной степени с суффиксом -***éе*** могут являться
> омоформами полным прилагательным среднего рода, например: *да́внее —
> **давнéе**, си́нее — синéе*.

**Несколько примеров** с формой сравнительной степени *давнее*:

*Однако ошибки эти гораздо многосторонней, глубже и **давнее**, чем кажется на первый взгляд* (Алекса́ндр Иса́евич Солженицын);

*Оно приходило с самого раннего детства, оно было **давнее**, чем все внезапное, как солнечный (хоть скорее было — лунный) луч, — ощущение, что...* (Анастасия Ивановна Цветаева);

*Я ведь знаю тебя **давнее** , чем многие другие, — и, может быть , лучше* (Михаил Леонович Гаспаров).

*Давно, давно я не видал Гориновых, **много давнее**, чем Вас, и очень хотелось бы повидать* (из письма В. Г. Короленко). http://korolenko.lit-info.ru/korolenko/pisma-korolenko/letter-289.htm

Comment: Спасибо, Слава, за Ваши изыскания! Вот еще один пример, думаю, достойный внимания: _Давно, давно я не видал Гориновых, **много давнее,** чем Вас, и очень хотелось бы повидать_ (из письма В. Г. Короленко). [http://korolenko.lit-info.ru/korolenko/pisma-korolenko/letter-289.htm]

Comment: Спасибо, Римма, за пример из письма Короленко! Можно, я добавлю его к своему ответу?

Comment: Да пожалуйста, с превеликим удовольствием — лишь бы на пользу.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Слава! Не понял только, запятую после "можно" в комментарии вы случайно поставили?

Comment: Нет, не случайно. Запятая после "можно" соответствовала интонации, с которой я мысленно произносил то предложение,  "находясь в здравом уме и твёрдой памяти"... Имел на неё право! ✍️

Answer (score 3):

Если наречие не имеет степени сравнения, то обозначить ситуацию можно с помощью других слов, в том числе усилительных (еще, гораздо)

Это было давно, в прошлом году. Нет, еще раньше, гораздо раньше, еще намного раньше. Это случилось давным-давно.

Answer (score 2):

Ни прилагательное "**давний**" ни образованное от него наречие "**давно**" не имеют степеней сравнения в силу своего специфического значения.

Comment: Наверное, не "да**ль**ний", а "давний"?

Comment: Да, ошибся. Хотел написать давний.

Comment: ИНТЕРЕСНАЯ МЫСЛЬ, никто здесь не сказал, почему наречие "давно" не имеет степени сравнения, ведь фонетических ограничений для этого нет (темно - темнее, давно - давнее). Значит, дело в особом значении, а в каком?

Comment: Вера, у наречия и прилагательного "давно" не может быть проявления признака в больше или меньшей степени. Кстати, в русском языке есть слово "давнее" но оно не обозначает сравнительной степени, а указывает на то, что произошло очень давно.

Answer (score 1):

Говорить "*давн**е**е*" можно, отчего ж не говорить?  Говорил же Жванецкий в каком-то монологе: "*тщательн**е**е*" (или "*тщательн**е**й*"? не помню).  В литературе такие приёмы изветсны.  Как там у Льюиса Кэролла, "*curious**er** and curious**er***"?

А разве словари не дают сравнительных форм наречий, если таковые существуют?  В Викисловаре значится, например, про "**давно**":

> Морфологические и синтаксические свойства
>
> дав-но́
>
> Наречие, обстоятельственное, времени; неизменяемое.

А про "**весело**" - по-другому чуть-чуть:

> Морфологические и синтаксические свойства[править]
>
> ве́-се-ло
>
> Наречие, определительное, качественное, также предикатив; неизменяемое. *Сравнительная степень* — **веселее, веселей**.

Так что пользуйтесь Викисловарём в отсутствие чего-либо лучше.

Comment: Ну, "тщательнее" все говорят. А как понимать то, что для "давно" не указаны сравнительные степени? Так, что их нету? А Вы пишете первой фразой, что есть. Не пойму я...

Comment: Может, Вы с юмором говорили в первом абзаце и Ваш ответ — сравнительной степени нет? Так как же?

Comment: Нет, по-моему *официальной* сравнительной степени нет. Есть разговорная, но в словари она ещё не попала.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!